# Who were Palpatine's assistants?

Tags: star-wars, darth-sidious, the-rise-of-skywalker

In the opening scene of *Rise of Skywalker* Palpatine is seen in a kind of workstation.

Half a dozen or so strange furry creatures are working away on the machinery around him.

Do we know anything about who these creatures were and why they were serving Palpatine?

Comment: There would be a certain symmetry in a Sith version of an Ewok...

Comment: Do you mean the creatures with mouths like chimpanzees'?

Comment: @RichS I can't remember much about them, or their mouths. They weren't dissimilar to Ewoks now I think about it.

Comment: A Sith version of an Ewok could be a Duloc?  Were they Dulocs?  The Ewok cartoon becoming canon would redeem this whole franchise for me.

Comment: I remeber my fav fan theory before TRoS came out being that Palpatine crashes on Endor after being thrown out of Deathstar(coz space flight is a force ability now) and uses Sith invasive mind control to turn Ewoks into "Sith Ewoks" that labor for him

Comment: I don't think the events of TLJ establish space flight as a force ability (I see the snark). Space survival, sure, but it's not any kind of new ability. We see the Jedi manipulate various amounts of matter with regularity. Yoda can pick up a starship. Palpatine and Yoda throw relatively large pieces of the senate chamber at each other. We see fine manipulation of objects in other sequences. A person needs about 8 liters (10 grams) of air a minute, so 100 grams for 10 minutes. I also don't have any trouble with Leia being able to pull herself a few hundred meters (at most) back to the ship.

Comment: @ChrisStrickland What's that got to do with Palpatine's assistants? Wrong question?

Comment: It doesn't answer the question, no.  It's a reply to the comment directly above it.

Comment: @ChrisStrickland Ah Ok.

Answer (score 4):

Here my 'long shot in the Dark Side' answer:
Palpatine's assistants are similar to the unidentified Dowutin Sith in the tomb on Moraband that housed the Sword of Khashyun. In *The Rise of Skywalker* they are shown in humanoid embodiments wrapped in bandages and assist or serve like the former medical droids in Palpatine Surgical reconstruction Center in *The Revenge of the Sith*.

[image: The mummified remains of a Dowutin Sith warrior]

[image: Palpatine's Assitants]

Comment: Where are the two photos at the bottom from?

Comment: @TheDarkLord - They are cropped stills from the movie.

Comment: And the comic..?

Comment: @TheDarkLord - The comic is from Wookieepedia:
https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Unidentified_Dowutin_Sith

Comment: I'm awarding the bounty for the research effort and because this is a plausible guess although I'm not accepting until a more definite answer appears (with the DVD extras or whatever).